# How to get an arraylist in a javascript file?

Tags: javascript

I'm here because I want to get an arraylist from database but when i refresh my page the function is not instantly executed. I want to use a for loop on that array but it doesn't initialize the array before entering in the for loop.

Here is my function to request the array from database :

```
function fetch_constraint(){

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        dataType: 'text',
        url: build_url(url_ttconstraints),
        async: true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(msg){
            constraints = JSON.parse(msg);
        },
        error: function (msg){
            console.log("error");
            show_loader(false);
        }
    })
    return constraints;
};
```

Then I call that function so the array can be in the head of the js file:

```
fetch_constraint();
```

as a result with console.log(fetch_constraint()); after the fetch function I get:
undefined

But when i use the function in the console it works and I get the array.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: `contentType: "application/json"` is nonsense. You are making a GET request. There is no request body to describe the type of.

Comment: `SON.parse(msg);` is silly. You can say `dataType: 'json',` instead of writing parsing logic yourself.

Comment: Ok thanks you Quentin